# best practise - different program modes / using variables to programatically decide how a form creates

Tags: c#, winforms, class

In a recent project of mine, i've got up to a good stage where theres a fair bit of work in there, but nothing that can't be changed / modified too easily. I've been asked now to add..how to describe this..different "modes" for my program, for example;

- a map view mode, where the program is more of a graphical display and everything works based off being drawn onto a map / other displays.
- a datagrid mode, where the program is based more on text and such.

I could store this information in a variable, for example even a string which holds "map" or "datagrid" and the program creates the gui / its processes based off this, or an enum, although this would mean i need to move things around a little more i think.

```
public string mode; 
// then use dropdowntools to set this to "map" or "datagrid"

public enum mode
{
   map,
   datagrid
};
// again use dropdowntools
```

am i best off moving the main portions of my UI coding / form to 2 seperate classes, one for map and one for datagrid and create these as required based off the users selection and, inevitably, the variable i have it set to?

i've seen this done in most applications where a user can change these sorts of options, but never seen the best practise for coding it.

currently i've thought of setting things out like this;

```
  public void pollDevices()
    {

            if (mode == "Map")
            {
                timer = new System.Timers.Timer(500);

                 for (int i = 0; i <= mDevices.Count - 1; i++)
                 {
                     IDeviceInterface deviceToPoll = mDevices[i];
                     timer.Elapsed += delegate { deviceToPoll.connect(deviceToPoll, this, exit); };

                 }
            timer.Enabled = true;
            }


            else if (mode == "Datagrid")
            {

            }
        }
```

but am i best to move the code blocks for different modes into other classes, call these from the mainGUI, so it's tidier and easier to read?

```
 public void pollDevices()
{

        if (mode == "Map")
        {
            //call method in map class that does this stuff.

        }


        else if (mode == "Datagrid")
        {
             //call method in datagrid class that does this stuff
        }
    }
```

If anyone has any input about how they'd go about doing this sort of thing, it'd be a great help. If you need any further information from me, just ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Break the display components down into individual controls, one for map one for grid
2. Create a common interface and data source used by both controls
3. Create a common class or set of classes that will provide the data for either control

Comment: i see. So i should create the interface which holds the templates for methods and such, then basically go with one of my original ideas of creating a class for each view, inheriting from the interface?

Comment: That's right - the key thing is to separate the concerns of displaying the data and retrieving it.